# What replaced Flash's vector printing capabilities?

Tags: flash, vector, printing

I know 15 years ago, in 2002, I could use Flash to draw some vector graphics on the user browser and then print it with a call of a function.

Then the user, maybe with the help of his printer *Fit to page* option, was able to print it on paper as big as he would, with no quality loss.

**Now Flash is dead and question is: what in 2017?**

What can I use to achieve the same result, something that gives me user interface and print as vector capabilities as Flash did in the last decade and a half with ease of use?

P.S.: I'm aware of HTML5 canvas, however I could not find specific information it can print on paper as vectors rather than bitmap.
P.P.S.: let the user download a PDF or a SVG is different thing from what I'm asking: print straight out form the browser.
P.P.P.S.: did I mentioned it worked in any browser the same? :)

Comment: Are you talking about printing from an SWF?

Comment: @BoltClock yes, exactly